# Linux SQL server windows SSMS connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux

I have a Red HAT system on oracle virtual box that I've been trying to set a mssql server up. 
-Also tried doing everything on SUSE vm but I've been probably doing the same thing wrong on that one aswell.-

I have the server up but was unable to connect the mssql server in linux from windows terminal or SSMS.

Get this as a terminal response on windows

```
ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 
2000 or earlier versions.
```

and below one on SSMS

```
Not associated with a trusted server connection
```

Not sure if I have some network configuration info wrong on vbox myb?

Might be using the wrong ip addr trying to connect aswell.
I use localhost to connect on virtual box.
Tried to connect by localhost ip, public ip and

```
sudo ip addr show eth0 | grep "inet"
```

command as well.

Any idea what could be the issue since I am quite sure both the sql server versions are up to date.

Comment: are you ping your linux server using ping with ipaddress?

Comment: This is the SQL Server 2016+ you're trying to connect right?

Comment: Just tried and found out ping requests time out and yes I am trying to connect 2016+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved upon changing network attached to on virtual box settings to bridged adapter with promiscuous mode on.**

In case anyone gets stuck on this